# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - FilePath artifacts not always deleted from fileShare

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are on ADS 2020.0.1
We are migrating to a new file server, we have noticed that drops on the new file server are not beeing deleted after the build run has been deleted.

I have created a test pipeline, where i drop to the old and new server.
After deleting the build, the artifacts are deleted on the old server, but not the new server.

`old build path: 116 chars - new build path: 142 chars`

The service account has modify permissions in both the old and new location. I am able to manually delete a file remotely while logged on as this account on one of the build servers.

I can see the cleanup job in the job history, it shows a red X, but i cannot see the details.

Question is, where can i see the logs of the delete artifacts task? i tried in the _oi page, but here it doesn't show anything.

We see this behaviour in classing and YAML pipelines

Comment: Do you have try to set the variable "system.debug" to true?

Comment: Yes just did, but after deleting still no logs are available